# High P-value of intercept is a problem?

Tags: regression

| Coefficients | Estimate | Std. Error | t value | Pr(>|t|) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| (Intercept) | 1.181 | 4.292 | 0.275 | 0.787599 |
| UVB | 1226.389 | 232.773 | 5.269 | 0.000152 *** |
| SurfaceSurface | 1.278 | 11.066 | 0.115 | 0.909837 |
| UVB:SurfaceSurface | -939.931 | 409.839 | -2.293 | 0.039134 * |

As you can see, the p-value of the intercept of my regression model is 0.787599, and it is so high. Does that mean it is not statistically significant? So do I need to drop the intercept?

Comment: Usually not.  See https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=regression+drop+intercept.

Comment: Please use markdown tables instead of images. This helps use less server space. There are specialized tools to make preparing markdown tables easier. I used [https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables) here, although I am not affiliated with them.